# How to change my data column based on the value of another column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to render my data table like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUr6z.png)
I have tried to do it with tidyr or dplyr, but the results are a bit less than ideal.
Can anyone help me to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In any questions, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with your dataset (or use a built-in dataset like `mtcars`) and any code you've tried out so far, even if it doesn't fully work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`uncount()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/uncount.html) function to "lengthen" your data according to `count`.

```
library(tidyr)

id <- c("A","A","B")
code <- c("S01", "A12", "B11")
count <- c(1,2,2)
df <- data.frame(id, code, count)

df %>% 
  uncount(count)
  id code
1  A  S01
2  A  A12
3  A  A12
4  B  B11
5  B  B11
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been thinking about this for a long time.